# Why Microsoft sites stopped working on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Usually I read Microsoft docs on Chrome. But suddenly it stooped to work.

For example trying to open https://docs.microsoft.com/, get the following error:

[image]

But it's working fine on Edge.

The same with https://www.microsoft.com/

Just interested: is it Google wants to block Microsoft or Microsoft wants to promote Edge?

Or it's problem only with my laptop?

**UPDATE**: I restarted my laptop and now https://www.microsoft.com/ is working but https://docs.microsoft.com/ still not. But it works in incognito window of Chrome.

Comment: For what it's worth, I use Chrome and both those URLs work for me. It must be something local to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved by clearing browser data:

[image]